# Parse String to sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, parsing

I getting response in program like

```
SyncCitiesResponse{
    SyncCitiesResult=anyType{
        CITY=anyType{
             CIT_CODE=1; 
             CIT_DESC_EN=NEW YORK; 
               }; 
        CITY=anyType{
             CIT_CODE=1; 
             CIT_DESC_EN=Alabama; 
              };};}
```

I dont know number of "Cities" and now i need to parse it and insert in `sqlite` table that have same name fields`(CIT_CODE,CIT_DESC_EN);`
Its there some method for this?
It is possible to parse it ?,  i was think about `regex`,but i am not sure how it work on `android`.

Thank's

Answer (score 0):

Is this a JSON response?

If so convert it to a JSONArray object then loop through each result and save this to your database on an individual record basis

Comment: I try to change it to json object, but i cant, or i dont know right way. It is response from service that return me SOAPOBJECT and this i get when i write String.valueOf(resultsRequestSOAP)

Comment: try JSONArray arr = resultsRequestSOAP and see what, if any errors you get

Comment: resultsRequestSOAP is type of SoapObject  , and when i try JSONArray cannot accept different type, maybe i can to convert it?

Comment: You should be able to do this, however it might be worth taking the string value and trying to convert that, check your output is a true json string using jsonlint.com, if it is then you should be able to use the string value as an array